# Validate an argument over another

Tags: python, argparse

I have two additional options and I need to validate the second taking into account first.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentTypeError
from os import getenv, path

def invalidArgument(value, text= None):
    raise ArgumentTypeError("%s %s" % (value, text))

def directory(value):
    if path.isdir(value):
        return value
    invalidArgument(value, "directory not found")

def parsing():
    parser= ArgumentParser("")
    parser.add_argument("-dir", type= directory, action= "store", default= "/home", help= "Base directory")
    parser.add_argument("-loc", action= "store_true", help= "Takes into account locale")
    namespace, other= parser.parse_known_args()
    if namespace.loc:
        l= getenv("LANG", "en")[0:2].lower()
        if l == "en":
            namespace.loc= False
        else:
            if path.isdir(path.join(namespace.dir, l)):
                namespace.loc= path.join(namespace.dir, l)
            else:
                invalidArgument(path.join(namespace.dir, l), "directory not found $LANG not valid")
    return namespace, other

if __name__ == "__main__":
    namespace, other= parsing()
    print("Base directory:", namespace.dir)
    print("Locale directory:", namespace.loc)
```

And I get (with ./tst.py -loc):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tst.py", line 32, in <module>
    namespace, other= parsing()
  File "./tst.py", line 28, in parsing
    invalidArgument(path.join(namespace.dir, l), "directory not found or $LANG not valid")
  File "./tst.py", line 8, in invalidArgument
    raise ArgumentTypeError("%s %s" % (value, text))
argparse.ArgumentTypeError: /usr/share/fr directory not found $LANG not valid
```

If I call with:

```
./tst.py
```

I need:

```
Base directory: /home
Locale directory: False
```

If I call with:

```
./tst.py -loc
```

I need:

```
Base directory: /home
Locale directory: /home/fr
```

If I call with:

```
./tst.py -dir=/home/foo -loc
```

I need:

```
Base directory: /home/foo
Locale directory: /home/foo/fr
```

Does anyone have an idea or track for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Locale(Action):
    def __init__(self, loc, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, value= False, option_string= None):
        l= getenv("LANG", "en")[0:2].lower()
        if l != "en":
            if path.isdir(path.join(namespace.dir, l)):
                value= path.join(namespace.dir, l)
            else:
                parser.error("%s %s" % (option_string, "directory not found or $LANG not valid"))
        namespace.loc= value

def parsing():
    parser= ArgumentParser("")
    parser.add_argument("-dir", type= directory, action= "store", default= "/home")
    parser.add_argument("-loc", action= Locale, loc= None, nargs= "?", default= False)
    namespace, other= parser.parse_known_args()
    return namespace, other
```

Comment: This behaves differently depending on the order of the `-dir` and `-loc` options.  If `-loc` is first it uses the default `dir` value, not the given one.  And what about the `type=directory`?  What does that do?

Comment: That is true. This should be explained in man page. I do not see how to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oneletter args with one dash, and manyletters args with two dashes:
-h, --help

Comment: In this case -h is only a shortcut to --help, it does not change the problem.

Comment: So, I have no idea, because I ran your code and it works properly, just as you wish. But I ran on python 2.7. Maybe, you didn't create directories?

Comment: Yes I have not create the directory for testing. The problem is the traceback. Thanks

Comment: Traceback - because you raise it manually - "raise ArgumentTypeError"

Answer (score 0):

The error message makes sense if that `/fr` directory does not exist.

If you want an error message with usage and exit, use `parser.error(...)`, rather than just raising an exception.

I've simplified your code, in part to fit common argparse usage, but more importantly to focus on getting the parsing right.  Since my LANG is 'en', I took that part of the testing out.  And testing for specific directories is a distraction at this point.

I think your main problem was the `type=directory` parameter.  That parameter is supposed to be a function that takes a string and returns what-ever.  It does not specify the kind of object that you want.  And since there isn't a `directory(astr)` function, that step fails.

```
def parsing():
    parser= ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
    parser.add_argument('-d',"--dir", default= "/home", help= "Base directory")
    parser.add_argument('-l',"--loc", action= "store_true", help= "Takes into account locale")
    namespace, other= parser.parse_known_args()

    if namespace.loc:
        l = 'fr'
        namespace.loc= path.join(namespace.dir, l)
    return namespace, other
```

various tests are:

```
1139:~/mypy$ python3 stack29283397.py
Base directory: /home
Locale directory: False
1144:~/mypy$ python3 stack29283397.py -l
Base directory: /home
Locale directory: /home/fr
1144:~/mypy$ python3 stack29283397.py --dir=/home/foo -l
Base directory: /home/foo
Locale directory: /home/foo/fr
```

Changing the `loc` test to:

```
if namespace.loc:
    l = 'fr'
    namespace.loc= path.join(namespace.dir, l)
    parser.error('%s directory not found'%namespace.loc)
```

produces:

```
1145:~/mypy$ python3 stack29283397.py --dir=/home/foo -l
usage: PROG [-h] [-d DIR] [-l]
PROG: error: /home/foo/fr directory not found
```

If you want to keep the `type=directory`, then you need to find or write a function with that name, e.g.

```
def directory(astring):
    # do something to validate this string
    # or transform it into something else
    return astring
```